# Add font awesome icon before heading?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to design my own homepage and using this [Read-Only](https://html5up.net/read-only) template.

I want to customize my headings a little bit so it would have an icon before.

Here is my code

```css
.icon {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-size: 1em;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    padding: 0.35em 0 0 3.5em;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    height: 0.5em;
    width: 48%;
}

.icon:before {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none !important;
    background: #4acaa8;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2.5em;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="icon fa-rss"></span> </i> <h3 style="display: inline">First Blog</h3> 
<p>This is the first blog<p>

<h3>Second Blog<h3>
<p>This is the second blog<p>
```

But, the icon and the first heading seem not vertically aligned. Also, how to adjust the size of the icon?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

1. Set the heading after the icon to `display: inline-block`
2. Remove `position: absolute` from `::before`, and instead set it to `display: inline-block`
3. Remove margins and paddings from `.icon`, and use `width` property to define how much space it takes up
4. Use `font-size` to change icon size. (not text-size)

```css
i+h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  /* edit this to change the size of the icon */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

.icon:before {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none !important;
  background: #4acaa8;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="icon fa-rss"></span> </i>
<h3>First Blog</h3>
<p>This is the first blog
  <p>

    <h3>Second Blog
      <h3>
        <p>This is the second blog
          <p>
```

Instead of using the [adjacent selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), you can add a class to any `h3` that follows an icon, and then apply styles to the class instead.

**example**

HTML

```
<i class="icon fa-rss"></i>
<h3 class="icon-heading">First Blog</h3>
```

CSS

```
.icon-heading {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  It works perfect. Does `i+h3 {
  display: inline-block;}` mean when `i` tag and `h3` tag are used together, they will display as `inline-block`. Will it override the style for `i` and `h3`?

Comment: `i + h3` means that any h3 tag that immediately follows an i tag will be targetted. I used this so that other h3 tags on the page would not get `display: block`. The `+` is called adjacent selector in CSS

Comment: It's really helpful! Thanks!